# WalkingDead Program - Finding zombies and orphans

Tags: c, ubuntu

For my school paper i need to write a program that monitors all the processes in /proc directory and recording notices when processes become zombie or orphan.

I know some commands which i need to use but i don't know how to implement in program.

There is code that finds in terminal either there is a zombie or there is not.

```
ps aux | awk '"[Zz]" ~ $8 { printf("%s, PID = %d\n", $8, $2); }'
```

There is a code that creates zombie process:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int pid;

    /* let's create a child process */
    pid = fork();
    if (!pid) {
        /* this is a child: dies immediately and becomes zombie */
        exit(0);
    }

    /* parent process: just asks for the user input */
    printf("Please, press enter after looking at the zombie process...");
    (void)getchar();
}
```

I have a code that creates orphan too but i won't put it here.

I don't need all the code for program i just need someone that will explain or guide me step by step what i need to do that i will finish my homework with positive result.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: No offence, if you try to make your question worthy enough of answering , no need to put **BOLD STATEMENT** at the end. :-)

Comment: FWIW, Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here.

Comment: I just wanted to make it more transparent, no need for editing in a second and comenting. If you don't want to help or you can't just don't read it.

Comment: What do you consider an "*orphan*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just make a loop executing the command you have with

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int system(const char *command);
```

That´s all you need

Comment: Was going to post an answer involving reading /proc/[proc_id]/stat, but questioner  likes this one.  Oh well.